# hashset datatype

Tags: java

How to declare a headset using double as datatype?

```
public HashSet priceSet() {
    Set<double> hSet = new HashSet<double>();  //<==== netbeans warn this line
    for (Map.Entry<String, Tablet> entry : tableMap.entrySet()) {     
        hSet.add(entry.getValue());
    }        

    return (HashSet) hSet;
}
```

what's the problems of this line?
Set hSet = new HashSet();

Comment: Side note: putting Tablet instances in a Set of Doubles won't work. And you may use new HashSet<Double>(tableMap.values()) (or the Set.addAll method) to copy all the elements of another collection tto your set.

Comment: entry.getValue() is a double value from that object.

Comment: Nope. entry.getValue() returns the value of the entry, which is a Tablet. You need entry.getValue().getValue(). You could also iterate on the map's values, rather than iterating on its entries, since you don't do anything with the key of the entries.

Comment: ok, thanks, problem fixed. should be getValue().getPrice();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set is used for storing objects, not primitives. So you should use wrappers to use it with primitives - like

```
Set<Double> hSet = new HashSet<Double>();
```

**edit**
provided you have some `double` variable, you add it like

```
double test = 0.0;
hSet.add((Double)test);
```

however `entry.getValue()` is `Tablet`, so it seems you need to use something like

```
hSet.add((Double)entry.getValue().getValue());
```

**edit2** actually `(Double)` isn't necessary

Comment: but use Double this line will be warned hSet.add(entry.getValue());, how to fix this line?

Answer (score 2):

Use wrapper class `Double` instead of `double`. This won't affect the actual code, but it's a common way of creating generic datasets.

Comment: but use Double this line will be warned
 hSet.add(entry.getValue());

Comment: See my comment on your answer. You're trying to put Tablet instances into a Set of Doubles. Obviously, this won't work. A Tablet is not a Double. Do you put salads into an egg box?

Answer (score 1):

it should be `Double` not `double` , `double` is primitive type and `Double` is wrapper class for `double`